# JavaScript 'foreign characters' regex failing to catch patterns

Tags: javascript, regex

Trying to set up a simple .jsp to test JavaScript regular expressions and avoid having to clean/build/republish my testing server every time I make a change. The existing code was taken from a project on which I was working to add recognition of Spanish characters, but this code as it is doesn't seem to catch any mismatches at all.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script language="JavaScript">
        function isValidTarget(target) {
            if (regexTarget.target.search(/^[a-zA-Z\#\@\!\&\.\*\-:;<>"',\?0-9 ]+$/) == -1) {
                alert("Your input contains one or more invalid characters.");
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="regexTarget" method="post" onSubmit="return isValidTarget(this)">
        Target: <input type="text" name="target"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to search the DOM node instead of its value.  Try this:

```
regexTarget.target.value.search(...)
```

Comment: Ah! Alright - I made a few code changes and, not knowing the right syntax, neglected to add "value" back. Such is the pitfall of learning a new language from existing code. Thanks a mint!

Answer (score 0):

You are naming the parameter `target`, but then you never use it. Either remove the parameter, or make use of it (eg. `if( target.target.search...`)

Comment: Ah! I see. My initial response to your post was, "Don't you mean regexTarget?" But, yes, it has a new name in this scope - as in, regexTarget would've worked had I passed it as such.

Believe it or not, they did let me out of Programming I. ;) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (target.target.value.search(/^[a-zA-Z\#\@\!\&\.\*\-:;<>"',\?0-9 ]+$/) == -1)
```

Comment: Ditto my response to Kolink. ;)